# Graphic RAM allocation for GTA V

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, graphics-card

I've bought GTA V PC version few days ago and as you know it's a heavy game and if you're gonna play it maxed out you will need more than 3 GB of graphic RAM. I have a HD 7870 2GB graphic card and 8GB DDR3 RAM on my system which runs Windows 8.1 X64. in [MSI After Burner](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/msi-afterburner-beta-download.html) when i check my graphic card's RAM it is 3072 MB, but in GTA V it only recognizes 2048 MB of it. i know it can be some VRAM that is allocated from main RAM to graphic card but i can't find any way to use it.

Is there any way, tool..etc that i can use all 3072 MB RAM on GTA V or other applications?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its probably using what it needs to. Try turning up the graphics settings, especially stuff related to textures to see what happens.

Comment: I set the texture to high and the memory needed in game was 2500 MB but in After burner it only used 1850MB. the game was running smooth though, it only got slow once in a few minutes. i also overclocked the core clock, memory clock and set power limits to +50%.